# How to center subequations and maintain sub-numbering

Tags: subequations

I'm trying to get a subequation with 3 lines to have all equations centered horizontally relative to each other.

Right now I have:

```
\begin{subequations}\label{eq:propArea}
    \begin{alignat}{2}
        A &= first~special~subequation \\
        B &= equation~much~bigger~then~others~above~and~below \\
        C &= smaller~equation
    \end{alignat}
\end{subequations}
```

[image]

As you can see equations are aligned at the `&` marks.

Using the `gathered` environment gives:

```
\begin{equation}\label{eq:propArea}
    \begin{gathered}
        A = first~special~subequation \\
        B = equation~much~bigger~then~others~above~and~below \\
        C = smaller~equation
    \end{gathered}
\end{equation}
```

[image]

As you can see it aligns the equations to their centers, but I loose the sub-numbering that was so useful...

How can I get the two things?

Comment: in a comment to the accepted answer, you say that you probably saw a reference to `gather` in another question.  to get a better overview of what's available, you should read the `amsmath` users guide; it's not very long.  `texdoc amsmath`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
\begin{subequations}\label{eq:propArea}
    \begin{gather}
        A = first~special~subequation \\
        B = equation~much~bigger~then~others~above~and~below \\
        C = smaller~equation
    \end{gather}
\end{subequation}
```

`equation` environment has only one number (tag), `gathered` is designed for in `equation`, meanwhile `gather` is for multi line equation where each line is numbered (tagged).

Comment: Thank you. Now that I think of it, I probably saw that use in other questions I looked at, but I didn't distinguish the names `gather` and `gathered`. Had to read your answer twice no catch the difference. lol

Comment: @A.Vieira ups, i miss your comment: meanwhile `gathered` is intended for use inside other math environment (as `equation` for example), `gather` is not. it had to be used as main math environment.  for more information see documentation for `mathtools` package